# Regex to match numbers written as words, digits or roman numerals

Tags: c#, regex, numbers, words, roman-numerals

I'm trying to match a number written as a word, digit or roman numeral. Here's a bunch of samples

```
CHAPTER 1
CHAPTER 2
CHAPTER THREE
CHAPTER IV
CHAPTER TWENTY TWO
```

I'm pretty bad at regex, here's what I've got so far.

```
(CHAPTER (([0-9]+)|(/* words - see below */)|( /* roman - see below */)))

// words
(TWENTY|THIRTY|etc)?( |-)?(ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|etc)?

// roman
(I|II|III|IV|V|etc)+
```

The statement catches CHAPTER 1, CHAPTER 2 and CHAPTER THREE, but tries to match IV as a word (I'm guessing its matching FIVE somehow?). TWENTY TWO Doesn't match at all.

Can anyone help? Here's the full regex

```
(CHAPTER (
([0-9]+)|
((TWENTY|THIRTY)?( |-)?(ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE)?)|
((I|II|III|IV|V)+)
))
```

NOTE:

The point of this is to convert these text representations to actual integers. I have methods to do this in each case, so I *do* need to distinguish between the various cases

Comment: Your `CHAPTER IV` is written here as `CHAPTER !V`, exclamation point vs `I`. If that's what's in your file, it won't match.

Comment: Unless there is a need to explicitly write these out, it would be easier to do `CHAPTER (\w+(?: \w+)?)`

Comment: @BobKaufman That's a typo in this instance. It's correct in the original

Comment: @hwnd I need to then convert each case to an int depending on what they are. I have working extension methods to do this but I need to first find which is which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already got parsers, which hopefully fail gracefully if given something which superficially looks like valid roman/text input but isn't, you could just call them all and see which pass.

If you don't just want to call them all, this regex should identify which parser to pass each input to.

```
var re = new Regex(
    @"CHAPTER (?:(?<arabic>\d+)|(?<roman>[IVXLCDM]+)|(?<text>[A-Z ]+))");
```

called for example as

```
var input = @"CHAPTER 1
CHAPTER 2
CHAPTER THREE
CHAPTER IV
CHAPTER TWENTY TWO";

foreach (Match match in re.Matches(input))
{
    if (match.Groups["arabic"].Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pass {0} to Arabic parser", match.Groups["arabic"].Value);
    }
    else if (match.Groups["roman"].Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pass {0} to Roman parser", match.Groups["roman"].Value);
    }
    else if (match.Groups["text"].Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pass {0} to Text parser", match.Groups["text"].Value);
    }
}
```

results in

```
Pass 1 to Arabic parser
Pass 2 to Arabic parser
Pass THREE to Text parser
Pass IV to Roman parser
Pass TWENTY TWO to Text parser
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex for roman numeral is: `\bM{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b`
Regex for digits: `\d+`
Regex for literal: `[a-z ]+`

combine all these in:

```
CHAPTER (?:(?<digits>\d+)|(?<roman>\bM{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b)|(?<literal>[A-Z ]+))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CHAPTER (?:\d+|(?:XVIII|XVII|XIII|VIII|XIV|XVI|XII|III|VII|XV|VI|IV|XI|IX|XX|III|II|X|V|I)|(?:(?P<d>TWENTY|THIRTY|FORTY|FIFTY|SIXTY|SEVENTY|EIGHTY|NINETY)?(?(d)(?: (?:ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE))?|(?:ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE|TEN|ELEVEN|TWELVE|THIRTEEN|FOURTEEN|FIFTEEN|SIXTEEN|SEVENTEEN|EIGTHEEN|NINETEEN))))
```

breakdown and explanation:

```
CHAPTER // match "CHAPTER " literally
    (?:// then either:
        \d+// 1: digits
        |
        (?:// or 2: roman numerals (up to 18) (note: make sure to order them by length!)
            XVIII|XVII|XIII|VIII|XIV|XVI|XII|III|VII|XV|VI|IV|XI|IX|XX|III|II|X|V|I
        )
        |// or 3: words
        (?:
            (?P<d>// first, one of the literals "TWENTY", "THIRTY", etc...
                TWENTY|THIRTY|FORTY|FIFTY|SIXTY|SEVENTY|EIGHTY|NINETY
            )?// ...if possible
            (?(d) // then, if the previous group matched...
                (?: // ...a space...
                    (?:// ...and the numbers "ONE" to "NINE"
                        ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE
                    )
                )?// ...if possible.
                |
                (?://otherwise, one of "ONE" to "NINETEEN"
                    ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE|TEN|ELEVEN|TWELVE|THIRTEEN|FOURTEEN|FIFTEEN|SIXTEEN|SEVENTEEN|EIGTHEEN|NINETEEN
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/kE0bS1/1)